# Editing size of h3 tag in wordpress on a one-off basis

Tags: css, html

I have a post on my WordPress site (I'm admin) that has H1, H2, and H3 tags.

I want my H3 tags for this post to more resemble my h4 tags in size. However, I don't want to break the hierarchy and just skip h3 tags and go from h2 to h4. I also only want to do this on this page, so I don't know that editing the theme is the way to go.

How can I achieve this? Do I just define the size of the h3 tag every time I use it in this post? Could I go into the theme and create a special h3 tag that I can use when I run into this?

I'm using the classic editor with a plugin called Classic Editor: Enables the WordPress classic editor and the old-style Edit Post screen with TinyMCE, Meta Boxes, etc. Supports the older plugins that extend this screen.

Comment: Are you using the Gutenburg editor to edit the post? Other editor? Theme template file?

Comment: @YourManDan I'm using a plugin: Classic Editor - Enables the WordPress classic editor and the old-style Edit Post screen with TinyMCE, Meta Boxes, etc. Supports the older plugins that extend this screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use `<h3>` tags that are the same size as your `<h4>` tags only on one page, add a specific class to each of the `<h3>` tags you'd like that size.

In the Classic Editor, you should have a "Text" tab where you can input custom HTML.
[image: Location of "Text" tab]
In there, type your `<h3>` tags with a custom class:

```
<h3 class="small-h3">Your text here</h3>
```

Then go to the "Appearance" > "Customize" tab in the WordPress dashboard. On the screen that shows up you should have a "Additional CSS" tab:
[image: Location of Additional CSS tab]

Type there your custom CSS for this style:

```
.small-h3 {
    font-size: 1.25em; /* or whatever size your h4 tags are */
}
```